# Creating ranges from sequential values, while maintaining other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find a way to consolidate sequential (consecutive?) numbers into a range, grouped by another column.

I've tried *pynumparser* and *itertools*, but I'm not clever enough to implement them to get the results I'm looking for. Looking for some assistance and/or ideas. Thank you!

##### Input:

```
| test_var   |   F1 |
|------------|------|
| ABC        |    1 |
| ABC        |    2 |
| DEF        |    3 |
| ABC        |    4 |
| ABC        |    5 |
| GHI        |    1 |
| GHI        |    2 |
| ABC        |    6 |
```

#### Goal output:

F1_range is supposed to represent the min and max of sequential values per test_var. Which there may be several sets.

A simple example is "GHI". For F1 there is only 1 set of sequential values, 1-2.

A more complicated example is "ABC", it has 2 sets of sequential values 1-2 and 4-6.

```
| test_var   |   F1 | F1_range   |
|------------|------|------------|
| ABC        |    1 | 1-2        |
| ABC        |    2 | 1-2        |
| DEF        |    3 | 3          |
| ABC        |    4 | 4-6        |
| ABC        |    5 | 4-6        |
| GHI        |    1 | 1-2        |
| GHI        |    2 | 1-2        |
| ABC        |    6 | 4-6        |
```

#### Sample input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'test_var': {0: 'ABC',
  1: 'ABC',
  2: 'DEF',
  3: 'ABC',
  4: 'ABC',
  5: 'GHI',
  6: 'GHI',
  7: 'ABC'},
 'F1': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 6}})
```

Comment: You have to edit **Sample input data** as well as you've changed **Input** and **Goal input**. Also `F1_range` should be clearly explained.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, apologies. For what it's worth I did update all the data it just wasn't in the same order, and while order shouldn't matter in the raw data I see how that was an error on my part. I'll clarify the F#_range fields. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the order _doesn't_ matter, than all you need is `pandas.groupby('test_var').apply(...)`. Also you have to replace then all ranges for `ABC` with something like `F1_range = 1-6` and `F2_range = 10-15` to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: I just simplified the data, and clarified the F1_range. As you pointed out in your answer, F1 and F2 were essentially just repeating the same process. The order doesn't really matter, but most solutions to problems like this do require sorting first.

Comment: The description of your problem is inconsistent. You show 3 parts for `ABC`. At the beginning the range is `1-2` for values `[1,2]`. In the middle it's `4-6` for values `[4,5]`. And at the end it's `4-6` for values `[6]`. How do you group records - by values in `test_var` or by continuous sequences of equal values?

Comment: What I was trying to demonstrate was that the data might not be sorted. You're correct, ABC is broken into 3 parts, but when sorted there are 2 sets of sequential numbers. 1-2 and 4-6. Values 1 and 2 are in the range 1-2 and 4, 5, and 6 are in the 4-6 range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to group equal neighbors along a column

#### Test data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'test_var': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'GHI', 'GHI'],
    'F1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 2],
    'F2': [10, 11, 1, 13, 16, 14, 2, 1]
})
```

We suppose that indexes are an ordinary `RangeIndex` starting from 0 with step 1.

#### Main steps

1. Find indexes where the value in *test_var* differs from previous neighbors.
2. Split the data at those indexes vertically with `numpy.vsplit`.
3. `join` min/max values across the columns of interest in each group of the previous split.

```py
columns = ['F1','F2']
ranges = [f'{name}_range' for name in columns]
df[ranges] = ''

test_var = df['test_var'].values
changed = np.zeros(len(df), dtype=np.bool)
changed[1:] = test_var[1:] != test_var[:-1]
groups = np.vsplit(df, df.index[changed])
sep = '-'

def get_range(index, column):
    data = df.loc[index, column]
    low, high = min(data), max(data)
    return f'{low}-{high}' if low < high else str(low)

for gr in groups:
    for col, rng in zip(columns, ranges):
        df.loc[gr.index, rng] = get_range(gr.index, col)
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: This looks like it works! I'll give it a few more hours in case there's a better answer, otherwise I'll mark this is answered. Thanks again for your help!